# Try to use query to vlookup and filter a set of raw data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I try to run this query:

```
=Query({'raw_13-19'!A:G},"Select * where C ={'Keyword'!G2:G19}", 1)
```

But it keeps returning:

```
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " <ID> "C "" at line 1, column 16. Was expecting one of: "(" ... "(" ...
```

I'm not quite sure why is this happening. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Since the range is within `{}`, you need to use the other select notation 'Col1,Col2,Col3' instead of 'A,B,C'.

Also `{'Keyword'!G2:G19}` won't work, but you should use `textjoin()` instead.

Try:

```
=Query({'raw_13-19'!A:G},"Select * where Col3 matches '"&textjoin("|",1,Keyword!G2:G19)&"' ", 0)
```

If you have a header column on `raw_13-19`, then change `, 0` at the end to `, 1`.

NOTE: the above will work with text fields, but if you have any issues, please share a mockup sheet so we can see the actual data scenario.